# I want to exclude a long "if else" statement to filter my data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to filter my prime faces data table by four properties: `priceCatalogSupplier`, `priceCatalogBusinessUnit`, `priceCatalog`, `priceCatalogItem`.

I was able to filter by each property independently.

```
 if(priceCatalogSupplier !=null && priceCatalogBusinessUnit==null && priceCatalog == null && 
       priceCatalogItem == null){
                              
 filterBypriceCatalogSupplier();
     
 } else if(priceCatalogBusinessUnit !=null && others null){
                         
     filterBypriceCatalogBusinessUnit();
   
 }
  

 public viod filterBypriceCatalogSupplier(){
        priceCatalog = ejbFacade.findByInt("PriceCatalog.Supplier", "supplier", priceCatalogSupplier));
 }
```

The if else continue for each not null properties and combing two not null properties and two null properties and so on

My question is there any way I can simplify the junk if-else statement into one simple JPA or Hibernate query?

Comment: And what if you have `priceCatalogSupplier !=null && priceCatalogBusinessUnit!=null`? Must write another `if else` piece? Consider redesign your data access interface.

Comment: of course, I have written all the possible combinations of the if-else statements including the one you mentioned. and it's working well. But in general, I needed to make it simpler by using one Hibernate or JPA query. Because in the future I may face a much longer if-else statement.